# AngularFire2 Observables - How to account for last removed item in a tree, in the UI?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

So I have a commenting system built into this app that I'm working on and when I remove comments from a list, all of them get removed from the DOM accordingly, except for the very last item.

I believe there is something happening in which, because the last item in the comment tree in Firebase is being removed, it's deleting the entire tree, thus disrupting the observable stream that was watching that tree. The last item does indeed get removed, however, the item sits in the DOM, even though it no longer exists in the database.

I'm not exactly sure how to deal with this kind of thing in my component.

Here is the function that calls the remove functionality:

```
/**
   *  Remove a message
   */
  removeMessage(messageId) {
    this._messages.removeMessage(this.requestId, messageId)
  }
```

Inside my ngOnInit(), I am subscribed to the messages stream as you can see here:

```
  this.getDiscussionObs = this._messages.getCheckRequestDiscussion(this.requestId).subscribe(messages => {
               if(messages) {
                 this.discussionMessages = messages;
               } else {
                 this.discussionMessages = [];
               }
             });
```

And here is my `getCheckRequestDiscussion()` function:

```
getCheckRequestDiscussion(checkRequestId) {

    // Get request ID
    return this._af.database.list(`/request_discussions/${checkRequestId}`,
        {
          query: {
            orderByChild: 'created_timestamp'
          }
        })
        .switchMap(messages => {

          return Observable.combineLatest(
            messages.map(message => {
              return this._af.database.object(`/users/${message.author_id}`)
            }),
            (...users) => {
              messages.forEach((message, index) => {
                users.forEach(user => {
                  if(message.author_id === user.$key) {
                    messages[index]['author'] = user;
                  }
                })
              })
              return messages;
            }
          )
        })
  }
```

Here is the remove function in my provider:

```
/**
   *  Remove a message
   */
  removeMessage(checkRequestId, messageId) {
    return this._af.database.list(`/request_discussions/${checkRequestId}/${messageId}`).remove();
  }
```

What's weird is that I've dealt with this issue before, except the DOM updates accordingly, but here it is not. Does anyone have any clue what's going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the implementation of `getCheckRequestDiscussion` look like?

Comment: hey @cartant, I've added the `getCheckRequestDiscussion` function. Anything stand out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely due to your using `combineLatest` with the `messages` array:

```ts
...
.switchMap(messages => {
  return Observable.combineLatest(
    messages.map(message => {
      return this._af.database.object(`/users/${message.author_id}`)
    }),
    ...
```

You've not checked the length of the array. And if it's empty, the observable returned by `combineLatest` won't emit anything.

You should do something like this:

```ts
...
.switchMap(messages => {
  return messages.length === 0 ?
    Observable.of([]) :
    Observable.combineLatest(
      messages.map(message => {
        return this._af.database.object(`/users/${message.author_id}`)
      }),
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks to you, the issue that has plagued time and time again is now solved. Thankyou so much that worked perfectly :)